# Mobx use class models to define observables

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I tried setting the observables as a map of class models but for some reason Mobx does not detect if the class models has change. i did some tinkering and found out that Mobx only detect changes to observables that is one of array, map, objects and primitives. heres an example.

so i read in the docu that mobx also support class instances as observables. There must be something i am doing wrong.

i went with the object type but is there any way to use class models as observables so that i can add some methods in it?

```js
class Task {
    @observable list = new Map();

    @action addTask = (data, type) => {
        // this works when i use this
        task = type === TASKTYPE.ROUTINE ? {
            ...Some Data
        } : {
            ...Some Data
        };
        // but not this
        task = type === TASKTYPE.ROUTINE ? new Routine({
            ...Some Data
        }) : new Todo({
            ...Some Data
        });

        this.list.set(task.id, task);
        updateTask(this.list);
    }

    // Whenever i call these actions below in some component it mutates the list only on the action block
    // but doesnt reflect the changes if i use the 2nd option above
    @action deleteTask = (id) => {
        this.list.delete(id);
        updateTask(this.list);
    }

    @action addTime = (item, amount = 10) => {
        const nItem = this.list.get(item.id);
        nItem.timeSpent = nItem.timeSpent + amount;
        this.list.set(item.id, nItem);
        updateTask(this.list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you see my answer? Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to make both the `Task.list` container and each relevant primitive of the `Routine` or `Todo` instance inside the container an observable. I don't use decorators so you'll have to check that the syntax is OK.

```
class Task {
    @observable list = new Map();
    @action addTask = (data, type) => {

        task = type === TASKTYPE.ROUTINE ? new Routine({
            id: "someId"
        }) : new Todo({
            id: "someOtherId",
            settings: {}
        });

        this.list.set(task.id, task);
        updateTask(this.list);
    }
}
class Routine {
    constructor(options) {
        //each primitive inside the class can be observed
        @observable this.id = options.id;
    }
}
class Todo {
    constructor(options) {
        @observable this.id = options.id;
        //you can also observe changes to objects
       @observable this.settings = options.settings;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.